# Notice: Object of class PDOException could not be converted to int in

Tags: php, xml, pdo

It's been many times I search on the net but I have not found anything useful. I have this error

> Notice : Object of class PDOException couldn't be converted to int in C : \ wamp \ www \ Score \ Administration \ Controller \ ajaxGestionOTP.php on line  183

By going to this place , the error seems to come from the variable `$e` , in the `echo ' < QueryReport >' + $ e ;` .

Here's the code , if someone has an idea or a track !

```
else if (isset($_POST['TODO']) && $_POST['TODO'] == 'ajouter') {

  try {

    $DATABASE->beginTransaction();

    if (isset($_POST['Actif'])) {
      $actif = 1;
    } else {
      $actif = 0;
    }

    if (!isset($_POST['OTP']))
    {
      $_POST['OTP'] = "undefine";
    }
    insertOTP($_POST['OTP'], $actif);

    echo '<etatrequete>';
      echo '<statut>OK</statut>';
      echo '<message>OTP ajouté avec succès</message>';
    echo '</etatrequete>';
    echo '</reponse>';

    $DATABASE->commit();

  } catch (Exception $e) {

    echo '<etatrequete>' + $e;
      echo '<statut>KO</statut>';
      echo '<message>Impossible d\'ajouter un nouvel OTP</message>';
    echo '</etatrequete>';
    echo '</reponse>';

    $DATABASE->rollback();
    error_log($e->getMessage(). ' | LIGNE ' . $e->getLine() . ' DANS ' . $e->getFile());

  }

  die();
```

Comment: which line is the line `183` ??

Comment: echo '<etatrequete>' + $e; This one sorry, but Marmar respond to me !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line is the problem:

```
echo '<etatrequete>' + $e;
```

The PHP operator for concatenating strings is `.`, not `+`.

```
echo '<etatrequete>' . $e;
```

Comment: Thanks Barmar, I was focused on other lines, and don't see this .. :)

Comment: Doesn't the error message tell you exactly which line has the problem?

Comment: That's true, but i was not thinking about '.' instead of '+', so i was thinking the error comes from elsewhere.

Comment: Just something Barmar, i had console errors before put the '.' instead of '+'. And no i have the same result it's not works but i can't see the console errors, nothing appears. Is it normal ?

Comment: Maybe you made another mistake when you fixed this. Check the error log file for syntax errors.